# Как красиво настроить выпадающий список с помощью css?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss

Подскажите пожалуйста вот у меня есть поле ввода с выпадающим списком, как его можно настраивать с помощью css, например я хочу увеличить расстояние между итемами, размер шрифта в выпадающем списке, колесико прокрутки, как это можно реализовать?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QCompleter, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        a = ['вырезка свиная', 'гречка', 'морковь', 'лук', 'масло растительное', 'масло сливочное',
             'голень куриная без кожи', 'овощи', 'филе куриное', 'фасоль стручковая',
             'перец болгарский', 'мука', 'рис', 'яйца', 'манка', 'хлеб бородино',
             'творог', 'овощи секрет хозяйки', 'кукуруза', 'котлеты лососевые',
             'сыр легкий', 'филе вареное', 'лопатка свиная', 'картофель', 'помидор', 'горошек']

        self.text = QLineEdit()
        self.com = QCompleter(a)
        self.com.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)

        self.text.setCompleter(self.com)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Test()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38084484/5909792) нашел подсказку о настройке стилей `QCompleter`. У `QCompleter` есть метод `popup`, что возвращает виджет от `QAbstractItemView`, если вывести `print(self.com.popup())`, то окажется, что эти виджет `QListView`. Значит, нужно можно стиль для `popup` и для `QAbstractItemView` (т.к. базовый) и для его потомков, типа `QListView`

Тут есть примеры стилей: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview

Но стили не работали для элементов. Поиск [подсказал](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39268-Styling-a-QAbstractItemView-item?p=181412#post181412), что `popup` нужно установить `QStyledItemDelegate` (импортировать из `QStyledItemDelegate`), а для ползунка нужно настраивать стили для `QScrollBar`:

```
        self.com.popup().setItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate(self))
        self.com.popup().setStyleSheet("""
        QAbstractItemView {
            background: black;
            font: 20px;
        }
        
        QAbstractItemView::item {
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            color: darkCyan;
        }
        
        QScrollBar:vertical {
            background-color: green;
            width: 35px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        """)
```

Весь код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QCompleter, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QStyledItemDelegate
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        a = ['вырезка свиная', 'гречка', 'морковь', 'лук', 'масло растительное', 'масло сливочное',
             'голень куриная без кожи', 'овощи', 'филе куриное', 'фасоль стручковая',
             'перец болгарский', 'мука', 'рис', 'яйца', 'манка', 'хлеб бородино',
             'творог', 'овощи секрет хозяйки', 'кукуруза', 'котлеты лососевые',
             'сыр легкий', 'филе вареное', 'лопатка свиная', 'картофель', 'помидор', 'горошек']

        self.text = QLineEdit()
        self.com = QCompleter(a)
        self.com.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
        self.com.popup().setItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate(self))
        self.com.popup().setStyleSheet("""
        QAbstractItemView {
            background: black;
            font: 20px;
        }
        
        QAbstractItemView::item {
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            color: darkCyan;
        }
        
        QScrollBar:vertical {
            background-color: green;
            width: 35px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        """)

        self.text.setCompleter(self.com)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Test()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает отлично

Comment: @Tesla, пожалуйста :)